# Connect to Cisco any connect VPN from java web application

Tags: java, vpn

My Web application running in AWS Ubuntu 18 Server. From the web application (Java) , I need to upload files to some US Government websites using FTP. But before connecting to FTP, we must be connected to their VPN and then only FTP will be connected. Each client has a unique VPN Hostname, group name, user name, and password. After the files are uploaded to FTP, we want to disconnect the VPN connection in the server via a web application.

So what I am looking for 
1) Execute a script from the web app in AWS Server to connect XXXX VPN1 and then FTP1 (this I have the code, no problem).
2. Execute a script from the web app in AWS Server to disconnect the XXXX VPN1

Any Help, please?

Answer (score 0):

1. Please install the vpnagent in your AWS VM instance
   /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpnagentd
2. To connect:
   printf 'USERNAME\nPASSWORD\ny' | /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn -s connect HOST
   Replace USERNAME, PASSWORD, and HOST
3. First make it work for one client, then you can change it dynamically to support "N" number of clients.
4. To disconnect:
   /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn disconnect
5. Invoke the custom shell scripts from the java application using RunTime Class (on step 2 to establish VPN connection, then upload the files and then invoke step 4 custom shell script).

Ref : https://superuser.com/questions/649614/connect-using-anyconnect-from-command-line

Comment: Senthil. Before using printf, i tried using /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn -s connect HOST. My VPN has Group Selection also. After entering the group, username and password, i got the following error, not sure why

Comment: >> notice: Checking for product updates...
  >> state: Connecting
  >> notice: Checking for customization updates...
  >> notice: Performing any required updates...
  >> notice: The AnyConnect Downloader updates have been completed.
  >> notice: Establishing VPN session...
  >> notice: Establishing VPN - Initiating connection...
  >> state: Disconnecting
  >> notice: Disconnect in progress, please wait...
  >> error: VPN establishment capability for a remote user is disabled.  A VPN connection will not be established.
  >> state: Disconnected
  >> notice: Ready to connect.

Comment: error: VPN establishment capability for a remote user is disabled.  A VPN connection will not be established.
  >> state: Disconnected

Comment: By default, only local users may connect via any connect client. You would need to edit the anyconnect client profile. Please change the  WindowsVPNEstablishment parameter to "AllowRemoteUsers" instead of "LocalUsersOnly.                           
 Ref how to enable it here : https://community.cisco.com/t5/firewalls/how-to-enable-cisco-anyconnect-vpn-through-remote-desktop/td-p/2883910

Comment: Senthil. Link inside the community is broken. Can you give me correct direction how to edi the profile in ubuntu 18 ?

Comment: i am able to find the profile for my client in /opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile. It is already there. See below

Comment: <RSASecurIDIntegration UserControllable="false">Automatic</RSASecurIDIntegration>
  <WindowsLogonEnforcement>SingleLocalLogon</WindowsLogonEnforcement>
  <WindowsVPNEstablishment>AllowRemoteUsers</WindowsVPNEstablishment>
  <AutomaticVPNPolicy>false</AutomaticVPNPolicy>

Comment: After mkaing the changes, restart the service / netowrk settings in that VM  and try it out ?!

Comment: No. I think I did not explain clearly. I went to /opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile and i found the file hostname. TMHP_EDI_VPN.xml. Here TMHP_EDI_VPN is my host. I opened the file and found that properties already there. So got confused what is going wrong ?